# How to install OS X again with no access to a recovery partition?

Tags: macos, unix, recovery, install, recovery-hd

I have a Mac running Fedora with no recovery partition and no access to any computer with Mac OS X. How can I reinstall OS X on this computer?

Answer (score 0):

If the Mac is new enough to support it [roughly late Snow Leopard or Lion as its original OS], [Internet Recovery](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314) would be the way to go.

Hold  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>R</kbd>  at the boot chimes to get started.

Comment: Tried this and it unfortunately didn't work. It is a Mac Mini 2012, though.

Comment: 'didn't work' in what way? Without another Mac to build a bootable installer on, it's your only way.

Comment: After the usual grey background it booted straight into GRUB.

Comment: Then I'd guess you'll have to wipe the drive first, so the Apple firmware can do its thing.

Comment: Try holding Alt (Option) at boot and wait a little while. From what I recall, after a minute, you should receive an option for Internet Recovery in the boot menu there.